# pandas set_index with NA and None values seem to be not working

Tags: pandas, indexing

I am trying to index a pandas DataFrame using columns with occasional NA and None in them.  This seems to be failing.  In the example below, df0 has (None,e) combination on index 3, but df1 has (NaN,e).  Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'k1':['4',np.NaN,'6',None,np.NaN], 'k2':['a','d',np.NaN,'e',np.NaN], 'v':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df1 = df0.copy().set_index(['k1','k2'])

>>> df0
Out[3]: 
     k1   k2  v
0     4    a  1
1   NaN    d  2
2     6  NaN  3
3  None    e  4
4   NaN  NaN  5

>>> df1
Out[4]: 
         v
k1  k2    
4   a    1
NaN d    2
6   NaN  3
NaN e    4
    NaN  5
```

Edit: I see the point--so this is the expected behavior.

Comment: I have looked at this a bit and as far as I can tell the data itself is fine. It just doesn't seem to be displaying the last row of 'k1' when it is NaN and is in a multi-index.  For example, type `df1.index` and you can see the last entry there, even though it's not showing up when you type `df1`

Comment: But isn't this expected behaviour though? the `None` value is being treated as `NaN` so the last 2 rows are equivalent so there is no need to display it?

Comment: For instance if `'k1':['4',np.NaN,'6',1,1]` you would see the same output with a single `1` displayed in the index

Comment: @EdChum  Ah, yes, you are exactly right.  None and NaN are essentially equivalent so this is just how a multi-index ought to display.  `df1.sort()` makes this more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, the `None` value is being converted to `NaN` and as the value is duplicated it isn't being shown:

```
In [31]:    
df1.index

Out[31]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['4', '6'], ['a', 'd', 'e']],
           labels=[[0, -1, 1, -1, -1], [0, 1, -1, 2, -1]],
           names=['k1', 'k2'])
```

From the above you can see that `-1` is being used to display `NaN` values, with respect to the output, if your df was like the following then the output shows the same behaviour:

```
In [34]:
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'k1':['4',np.NaN,'6',1,1], 'k2':['a','d',np.NaN,'e',np.NaN], 'v':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df1 = df0.copy().set_index(['k1','k2'])
df1

Out[34]:
         v
k1  k2    
4   a    1
NaN d    2
6   NaN  3
1   e    4
    NaN  5
```

You can see that `1` is repeated for the last two rows